# Switch vertical JScrollBar min/max location

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollbar

I have a *vertical* `JScrollBar` which default behaviour is to show the thumb at the *top* when the scrollbar value is at the model *minimum*.

I'd like to have the opposite behaviour: the thumb would be at the *bottom* when the value is at the minimum.

I have tried `setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)` and it works for *horizontal* scrollbars but not for vertical ones...

How can I get it to work as expected (without creating a full `ScrollBarUI` if possible)?
Is that expected behaviour (a kind of "UI inconsistency"* between horizontal and vertical scrollbars, or a missing `ComponentOrientation.BOTTOM_TO_TOP` constant)?

Here is some SSCE that illustrate the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    int orient = JScrollBar.VERTICAL; // <<--- Change to HORIZONTAL
    JScrollBar sb = new JScrollBar(orient, 0, 100, 0, 1000);
    sb.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); // <<--- Works only for HORIZONTAL
    sb.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
        @Override public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getValue());
        }
    });
    f.add(sb);
    if (orient == JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL)
        f.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 100);
    else
        f.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 500);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

*: "inconsistency" because if it reverses the thumb for horizontal, I would expect the thumb to be reversed as well for vertical...

EDIT: The scrollbar is used to control scrolling in a map that can be configured to have its origin at the top-or-bottom of the screen, going down-or-up, or at the left-or-right, going right-or-left (it has to match a physical setup, so is configurable). Handling the left-or-right setup is just setting the scrollbar to horizontal, with right-to-left orientation, but the same is not working for vertical.

I also checked the source of `BasicScrollBarUI` and it indeed handles the `getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()` *only* when the scrollbar is `HORIZONTAL`. So it is indeed expected behaviour (just not the one *I* expected...).

Comment: *I would expect the thumb to be reversed as well for vertical...* - it is not an inconsistency. The component orientation is right-to-left, not down-to-up. This is because of how languages work. Some languages are read left-to-right and top-to-bottom. Others are right-to-left and top-to-bottom. Bottom-to-top is not supported.

Comment: *when the scrollbar value is at the model minimum.* - how are you setting the value of the model? Maybe you can override the `setValue(...)` method of the scrollbar to calculate the value as: maxValue - value and then invoke super.setValue(...) with the result of the calculation. Or maybe you can override the getMin/Max value methods to return the opposite. I'm not really sure I understand the usage of this feature.

Comment: @camickr I was hoping there was an unknown-to-me property to set somewhere but I might resort to overriding the `get/setValue()` methods. I'm setting the value through `getModel().setRangeProperties()` so I might also be able to provide a different type of `BoundedRangeModel`?
See my edit for a use-case.

Comment: An interesting question, although I think that relying on the component orientation may not be appropriate here. The scroll bar is a view for a `BoundedRangeModel`. This model enforces the constraint `minimum <= value <= value+extent <= maximum`, so for some "simple model-based workarounds", you're out of luck. But considering that the scroll bar is *also* just a **view** from your application's perspective, couldn't the mapping from a range like [0,10] to the range [10,0] be done **in** your application, at the point where these values are actually *used*?

Comment: @Marco13 indeed that's where I was heading and will probably end up doing. I actually started with going from [0,10] to [-10,0] and checking `getValue() < 0`, but it started to get dirty at some point, probably due to a late evening coding though... ;)

Comment: @camickr overriding `setValue()` is working when tracking the thumb with the mouse, but not when the UI is triggering a block scroll, as it uses the mouse position relative to the thumb to determine the direction. I guess the real solution would be to implement a proper `ScrollBarUI` but that would be a lot of work for such a minor functionality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subclassing `JScrollBar` with a `getAdjustedValue()` that does the translation. The idea is to "reverse" min and max, so `[min;max]` becomes `[-max;-min]`. Then we have to take the extent into account when adjusting the model value, as the bottom of the thumb (`value + extent`) is the value we want:

```
public static class MySB extends JScrollBar {
    private boolean inv;
    public MySB(int orient, int value, int extent, int min, int max, boolean inv) {
        super(orient, inv ? -value-extent : value, extent, inv ? -max : min, inv ? -min : max);
        this.inv = inv;
    }
    public int getAdjustedValue() {
        int v = super.getValue();
        if (inv)
            v = -(v + model.getExtent());
        return v;
    }
}
```

Then modified the SSCE above, adding `sb.getAdjustedValue()` in the AdjustmentListener:

```
...
MySB sb = new MySB(orient, 0, 100, 0, 1000, true);
sb.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
    @Override
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getValue()+", "+((MySB)e.getAdjustable()).getMyValue());
    }
});
...
```

[image: Scrollbar]

```
-100, 0
-200, 100
-200, 100
-200, 100
-300, 200
-300, 200
```

We see the original value, and the corrected one. I initially started subclassing the model and overriding `getValue()` but it messed up the page up/down and arrows behaviour.